# C# MVVM Model Graph Message Mediator or INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, graph, model, inotifypropertychanged, mediator

I am developing a C# MVVM WPF app and have problems to decide whether I should use the message mediator pattern or simple INotifyPropertyChanged for my UI 'live' Model change notifications. The problem in particular is that my model represents a graph with lots of 'live' objects that all have properties where different viewmodels will be interested in the changes at some point. I have about 3-5 viewmodels active that need notification of model changes. Some changes might be nested deep inside the models 'grandchildren'.

I tried to compare both messaging techniques, mediator pattern and INotifyPropertyChanged, and think that the mediator is better suited for change notifications between different modules/systems. My viewmodels definitely need the initial values of the model upon initialization and then change notifications afterwards. INotifyPropertyChanged seems to be the optimal choice in my case, but I am a bit skeptic, because I think lots of nameof(e.PropertyName) switch cases are not very elegant. Are there better alternatives for this problem?

Comment: _Mediator_ is to decouple components. As any pattern it has a price and will add certain complexity. I agree that the very generic `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is not comfortable as it requires switches. It serves a different purpose and is meant to be consumed by the framework (data binding engine) in the first place.  If decoupling is not an issue I would go with dedicated i.e. named events. The code reads much better and you would eliminate the switch statements. It's better to have an event named `PriceChanged` than just a generic `PropertyChanged` and filter the `Price` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is typical for such cases, you could have both ways. You will obviously not be able to avoid using `INotifyPropertyChanged` because this is the WPF way of handling MVVM-based Data Binding, so all your view-models will be at least basic implementations of this interface.

I suspect that you might simply need both. I would not suggest using the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-based pattern inside your model. The reason this interface was created was to base the observer pattern on actual property names as **strings**. This was pretty much a "one-way street", as `XAML`, the typical "design" language supporting WPF, is parsed in a ["stringly"](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped) manner, leaving few efficient alternatives. In my humble opinion, there is almost no reason that you would want to force notifications throughout your model to be as weakly-typed (stringly-typed, in fact) as this scenario, so I would suggest avoiding `INotifyPropertyChanged` if you have a relatively voluminous Domain Model.

Messaging would probably be the way to go, maintaining strong-typing with message type registrations and whatnot, unless you would like to consider other alternatives, such as simple C# events, or even combine both. While at it, try to stick and adhere to hierarchy and encapsulation as strongly as possible but also as weakly as practical*.

(*I mean, if some of your Domain objects reach multiple nesting levels, then, occasionally, it may be more practical to bypass hierarchy and let, for example, grand-grandchildren send messages of their own, instead of notifying their parents' parents through events, and letting these parents' parents **then** send the corresponding notification messages. In typical OOP programming, compromises are constantly weighted against practicality and time availability).

Comment: Good to hear that there's no definitive right answer on that topic. Msdn says model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to propagate changes to VM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/gg405484(v=pandp.40)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . I also think that a mix of notification systems might be the way to go. For now I stick to INotifyPropertyChanged until I find it too painful to compare the strings.